# stdlogic strangely resolved in vsim

Tags: vhdl

I want to make a basic simulation of a SPI slave by doing the following:

```
miso_i <= mosi after 24 ns when falling_edge(sclk);
miso_i <= 'L';
miso_oe <=  '1' after 21 ns when ncs = '0' else '0' after 50 ns;
miso <= to_X01(miso_i) when miso_oe ='1' else '0';
```

When simulating with ModelSim, miso_i still starts with 'U' value, leading to some 'X' in miso. Shouldn't resolution of both drivers of miso_i always lead to miso being correctly driven?

Comment: One of the drivers is effectively `U` for at least 24ns.

Comment: What the simulation shows is that miso_i stays 'U' until 24 ns after the first falling edge of sclk. This behaves as if the weak driver did not exist. I do not understand why.

Comment: Right. The weak driver is exactly that : weak. `U` can overpower it, which allows simulation to catch errors such as other drivers that aren't driving valid values.

Comment: Maybe you could initialise `miso_i` to `'Z'` where it is declared

Comment: Thanks! that was too dumb, I could not see it. I just had to set an initial value to miso_i when declaring the signal.

Comment: shall i make that an answer?

Comment: If possible, you can even remove the question at all. It was really  dumb.